# Calculating daily growth using previous row value in new column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query below that shows size of a database and when this data was collected. I am trying to create a new column that has "average daily growth" which would be determined by the size on the previous day.

If my query captures data from multiple databases/instances how can I do this for each database? As seen in here[image: photo]

I am trying to calculate daily growth per database using the "DB Size mb" column and would like a new column called "LastDayGrowth"

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        c.instance_name ,
        a.database_name ,
        CONVERT (DATE, SWITCHOFFSET(CAST (a.collection_time AS DATETIMEOFFSET),
                                    '+00:00')) AS 'Collection Time' ,
        'LDF mb' = ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) ,
        'MDF mb' = ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) ,
        ( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize) + CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) )
          * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) AS 'DB Size mb' ,
        'Reserved mb' = ( a.reservedpages * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) ,
        'Data mb' = CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.pages) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ,
        'Index mb' = ( a.usedpages - a.pages ) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ,
        'Unused mb' = ( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.reservedpages)
                          - CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.usedpages) ) * 8192
                        / 1048576.0 ) ,
        'Unallocated mb' = ( CASE WHEN a.dbsize >= a.reservedpages
                                  THEN ( CONVERT (DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize)
                                         - CONVERT (DEC(15, 2), a.reservedpages) )
                                       * 8192 / 1048576.0
                                  ELSE 0
                             END )
FROM    MDWDB.snapshots.disk_usage a
        INNER JOIN MDWDB.core.snapshots_internal b ON a.snapshot_id = b.snapshot_id
        INNER JOIN MDWDB.core.source_info_internal c ON b.source_id = c.source_id
ORDER BY c.instance_name ,
        a.database_name ASC;
```

I have tried this using the "LAG" function but did not succeed. I tried it like this:

```
LastDayGrowth = DATEDIFF(DAY,
                         LAG(( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize)
                               + CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) )
                             * 8192 / 1048576.0, 1, NULL) OVER ( ORDER BY a.database_name, ( ( CONVERT(DEC(15,
                                                      2), a.dbsize)
                                                      + CONVERT(DEC(15,
                                                      2), a.logsize) )
                                                      * 8192
                                                      / 1048576.0 ) ),
                         ( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize)
                             + CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) ) * 8192
                           / 1048576.0 ))
```

Any tips, or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the Growth calculation?

Comment: "Db size mb" column.... previous row compared to the current row. for all rows for a given database in the dataset.

Comment: I meant is it: current row - previous row OR current row * .1 + 12^2 - previous *.5 +1235.  "Compared to" is a bit ambiguous and could mean anything depending on who is asking.

Comment: current row - previous row. Sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use LAG()

```
'DB Size mb' - 
    LAG('DB Size mb') OVER (PARTITION BY c.instance_name, a.database_name ORDER BY a.Collection_time ASC) as DB_SIZE_CHANGE
```

Comment: do you know what could cause this error "The function 'LAG' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."

Comment: @choloboy7 - see edit.  But please try to understand... this LAG statement is not hard to understand.

Comment: i see it produced the same output as the lag i attempted. your method is much cleaner though. thanks

Comment: can you use lag to calculate the % growth also? (for curiousity)

Comment: Here is a hint -- % growth is `(CurValue - PriorValue / PriorValue) * 100`  (so a db goes from 50gb to 75gb we say it had 50% growth or 75-50 = 25 / 50 = .5 * 100 = 50) .  You have the way to find CurValue and PriorValue in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88089/discussion-between-choloboy7-and-hogan).

Answer (score 1):

Doing a self join to the table so you can have a current date and a previous date should work.  The `ISNULL` is for the first day recorded or if there is no data for the previous day.  You can change it to a case statement that handles it but you should get the general idea.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        c.instance_name ,
        a.database_name ,
        CONVERT (DATE, SWITCHOFFSET(CAST (a.collection_time AS DATETIMEOFFSET),
                                    '+00:00')) AS 'Collection Time' ,
        'LDF mb' = ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) ,
        'MDF mb' = ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) ,
        ( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize) + CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) )
          * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) AS 'DB Size mb' ,
        'LastDayGrowth' = (( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize) + CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.logsize) )
          * 8192 / 1048576.0 )) - isnull((( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), d.dbsize) + CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), d.logsize) )
          * 8192 / 1048576.0 )), 0), 
        'Reserved mb' = ( a.reservedpages * 8192 / 1048576.0 ) ,
        'Data mb' = CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.pages) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ,
        'Index mb' = ( a.usedpages - a.pages ) * 8192 / 1048576.0 ,
        'Unused mb' = ( ( CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.reservedpages)
                          - CONVERT(DEC(15, 2), a.usedpages) ) * 8192
                        / 1048576.0 ) ,
        'Unallocated mb' = ( CASE WHEN a.dbsize >= a.reservedpages
                                  THEN ( CONVERT (DEC(15, 2), a.dbsize)
                                         - CONVERT (DEC(15, 2), a.reservedpages) )
                                       * 8192 / 1048576.0
                                  ELSE 0
                             END )
FROM    MDWDB.snapshots.disk_usage a
        INNER JOIN MDWDB.core.snapshots_internal b ON a.snapshot_id = b.snapshot_id
        INNER JOIN MDWDB.core.source_info_internal c ON b.source_id = c.source_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MDWDB.snapshots.disk_usage d 
            ON a.database_name = d.database_name 
            AND c.instance_name = d.instance_name
            AND DATEADD(day, -1, a.Collection_time) = d.Collection_time
ORDER BY c.instance_name ,
        a.database_name ASC;
```

EDIT: added "," where missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I get an error on " AND a.instance_name = d.instance_name" saying invalid column name.

Comment: Oops, thought instance_name came from a.  Changed it to c.

Comment: since instance_name comes from c then should it be c.instance_name = c.instance_name? since we are joining on itself?